# How to save default Search and Replace options in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On my install of Visual Studio 2013, the Search and Replace dialog reverts to these settings every time it is launched:

1. Match Case: Yes
2. Whole Word: Yes
3. Scope: Current Project

[image]

Those settings don't match my normal workflow so I have change them the first time I do a search and replace after opening VS. Is there a way to change the default settings for this feature?